# Run robot tests on multiple ips

Tags: automation, robotframework, ip-address

I am very new to robot framework.
I have a test where I have to check logins on different ip one after another.
Is it possible to achieve using robot tests ?
If yes , how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate connections from different networks you must have appropriate number of network interfaces on the robot machine. Then you have to write some keyword to set one interface "up" and other "down" (select by interface name for example). Create copies of your test and use this keyword as test setup with relevant interface name.

```
Test #1
    [Setup]   Set Interface name1
    Your test

Test #2
    [Setup]   Set Interface name2
    Your test
```

If you want to test connections from different IP from one network, you have to write keyword to change IP, then the same

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it through loop inside the Testcase. see below example with explanation.

```
Check Login                                             # TC name here
    [Tags]    login                                     # just a Tag
    @{IP_ADDRESSES}=     ${IP_Addr1}    ${IP_Addr2}     # List of ip addresses, you can also read from somewhere else
    : FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{IP_ADDRESSES}        # looping on ip addresses list
    \    login    ${ELEMENT}                            # use a login keyword which will actually test the login functionality.
```